# Use HTC Diamond as a access point

Tags: windows-mobile

I would like to use my HTC Diamond as an Access point for my itouch. Can any one help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.wmwifirouter.com/
I don't know if it works on the Diamond. It does work on the Touch Pro. Also you need to have an internet connection sharing plan from your provider. If you don't, you are breaking your terms of service and your provider can bill you according if they figure it out.